# Printing the data and placement of tree elements

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, root

I have to print `elements` of a `tree` based on the levels of the `tree`. I have to use `recursion` to complete this objective, however; I am only returning the `root data`. I apparently disregard the `children`.

```
/**
  * A binary tree in which each node has two children.
  */
public class BinaryTree {

    private Node root;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty tree.
     */
    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a tree with one node and no children.
     *
     * @param rootData the data for the root
     */
    public BinaryTree(Object rootData) {
        //
        root = new Node();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.left = null;
        root.right = null;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a binary tree.
     *
     * @param rootData the data for the root
     * @param left the left subtree
     * @param right the right subtree
     */
    public BinaryTree(Object rootData, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right) {
        //
        root = new Node();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.left = left.root;
        root.right = right.root;
    }

    class Node {

        public Object data;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        public String printTree(int level) {
            String strVal = "";
            strVal += root.data;
            if (root.left != null) {
                strVal += this.left.printTree(level + 1);
            }
            return strVal;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the height of the subtree whose root is the given node.
     *
     * @param n a node or null
     * @return the height of the subtree, or 0 if n is null
     */
    private static int height(Node n) {
        //
        if (n == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the height of this tree.
     *
     * @return the height
     */
    public Object data() {
        //
        return root.data;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the left subtree of this tree
     *
     * @return the left child of the root
     */
    public BinaryTree left() {
        //
        BinaryTree result = new BinaryTree();
        result.root = root.left;
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the right subtree of this tree
     *
     * @return the right child of the root
     */
    public BinaryTree right() {
        //
        BinaryTree result = new BinaryTree();
        result.root = root.right;
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new right child
     *
     * @param child the new right child
     */
    public void setRight(BinaryTree child) {
        //
        BinaryTree result = new BinaryTree();
        result.root = root.right;
        result = child;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new left child
     *
     * @param child the new left child
     */
    public void setLeft(BinaryTree child) {
        //
        BinaryTree result = new BinaryTree();
        result.root = root.left;
        result = child;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        //
        root.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        //

        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public String printTree() {
        //
        return root.printTree(0);
    }
   }
```

I don't understand why I'm only returning the root.

Comment: Are you trying to print all nodes at a give level, or just all nodes?

Comment: check out my solution and see if it is what you need.

Comment: are you forced to use this structure? It looks like you've mixed the function of Node and BinaryTree classes. You only need one or the other, check out my answer as an example.

Comment: Yes I am forced to use this kind of structure.. It would be much simpler if I'm allow to use a node param to pass through the recursion..

Comment: Are you trying to print only nodes at a give level, or just all nodes?

Comment: then why are you even passing int level to the printTree function?

Comment: The method is suppose to return nodes at a given level, but once the recursion is done it returns all the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values for `left` and `right` are never being set, they will always be null

Also a better way would be like this

```
private String strVal = "";  // StringBuffer would be better

String result = printTree (root);

public String printTree(Node n) {

    if (node.left != null) {
        strVal += node.toString();
        printTree  (node.left);
    }
    if (node.right != null) {
        strVal += node.toString();
        printTree  (node.right);
    }
    return strVal;
}
```

The above method uses the traditional way of passing the node to the recursive method.

Comment: Before my if statements, could I do left = root.left and right = root.right to set them?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - why don't you try it?  Do you even need these variables?

Comment: Which variables, I attempted it and I am still returning the first element.

Comment: `left` and `right` - why not just use `root.left` and `root.right` - just asking.  Want to update your code if it is not working?

Comment: I did that instead, you're right left and right were unneeded, I could have just called root.left and root.right

Comment: I feel that it has something to do with my strVal += printTree(level+1). I getting a new level, but am I also still retrieving the old root.data?

Comment: Sorry, in you code `strVal = (String) root.data;` you are never setting the value of `root` so it is always retrieving the same `root.data`

Comment: How would I set the `value` of `root`? in my `If statements`, before my `print` call would I do `root.data = left.data` etc